# "username" parameter coming back with more than I gave it!

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is really weird - I've got a MVC app running, including a `Login` method in my `ServicesController` class:

```
public ActionResult Login() {
  var p = Request.Params;
  var userName = p["username"];
  var password = p["password"];
  // etc...
}
```

The weird thing is that when I call the service with the request:

```
/services/login?username=myusername&password=password
```

I get into the code and find that `userName` is "anotherusername,myusername".  Depending on what browser I'm using, I get different values in place of "anotherusername", which I recognize from some other apps I'm developing.  So is "username" some kind of reserved word that one shouldn't use as a parameter name?  What other reserved words are there that cannot be used safely as parameters?

Comment: Are you also _POST_'ing to the page? Do you have form elements with the same IDs?

Comment: @Oded - no page, it's just a service that returns xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request.Params` combines values from `Request.QueryString`, `Request.Form`, `Request.ServerVariables` and `Request.Cookies`. I would expect that the second value is either a server variable or a cookie. You could find out by checking each collection for your request.

Try checking the `Request.QueryString` (GET request) or `Request.Form` (POST request) instead.

Comment: Yep, you were right: I found the offending parameters in a cookie - from a different app!  That's really weird though... why did my request think I wanted to know about that cookie?

Comment: Are your applications on the same domain? If you are doing this in your development environment and using localhost then you will get cookies from every application that you have been using, even if they are on different ports. This will mainly be an issue if you use persisted cookies or if you are testing multiple applications on different ports concurrently.

Comment: Yip, different apps, all on localhost, different ports. OMG, they should put a warning label on these things!  So what's the workaround, other than using different parameter names for every app I'm working on?

Comment: Personally I use the Request and Form collections as ActionMethods tend to handle either POST or GET. If you are not testing the apps concurrently then deleting all localhost cookies when switching apps would resolve the issue. I have previously created different sites through IIS so that applications can have different domains (this would need some host entries so that the different domains resolved to 127.0.0.1) If you are using Windows XP this is problematic due to IIS limitations, it works find on Windows 7